# Can I deploy to GitHub, using git, without using an SSH key?

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

I am setting up a chromebook for someone who will need to use git to deploy projects to Github. In my personal environment I use an SSH key to secure my deployments to my Github repositories. However, I cannot figure out how to set up an SSH key on a chromebook. Is there a way to deploy to github, through git, but not use an SSH key?

Comment: Yes, it should just ask for a user name and password instead of using an SSH key, if none is set up. Those credentials will then be validated against your repo's security. Did you try it yet?

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/867023

Comment: You can do it without SSH but wouldn't it be better to figure out how to use SSH?

Comment: @underscore_d, that's not accurate. It depends on the remote URL. An SSH URL (i.e. `git@github.com:...`) requires an SSH key. There is no way to push to such a remote with a password. However, _HTTPS_ remote URLS (i.e. `https://github.com/...`) can use a password.

Comment: OP, search for "github https" and go from there.